# match trailing slash with Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I try to match a trailing / like this:

```
type(re.match('/$', u'https://x.x.x/'))
<type 'NoneType'>
```

However, this one does match:

```
type(re.match('.*/$', u'https://x.x.x/'))
<type '_sre.SRE_Match'>
```

Using Perl the first pattern does match:

```
perl -e 'print "true" if "https://example.org/" =~ /\/$/'
```

How can this behavior be explained?

Comment: since you are using **Greedy** pattern that eats everything till end of line. Try `.*?(/)$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`re.match`  search your pattern from beginning of you string. Since your string doesn't start with a '/', `re.match('/$', u'https://x.x.x/')` returns nothing.

You need to use `re.search('/$', u'https://x.x.x/')` to find your last slash.

Comment: Thanks, this works. So in pythonic re the $ is not part of the pattern?

Comment: `$` means end of the line.

Comment: @rhoerbe Like Avinash said, $ means end in re. Please confirm this as an answer so that others could find what they want efficiently. Thanks!

Comment: Still the difference to perl regex is weird. The '/' is attached to the end-of-line, why does python need a search instead of a match? This is not perl-specific, I tried the equivalent in vi and grep, and they behave like perl.

Comment: @rhoerbe =~ in Perl equals re.search in Python. re.match('pa', s) means string has to be started with 'pa', which equals =~ '^pa' in Perl. re.search('pa', s) means seeking if there is 'pa' in s, which equals =~ 'pa' in Perl. There are indeed differences between both languages.

Comment: Thanks! This was what I missed. I assumed that re.match equals perl's match, but this is a fallacy.